# Why do I get "parser name defined to default :"parse" when I try to run my lex and yacc program?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yacc, lex, bisonc++

I just installed Lex and Yacc in my Ubuntu Virtual Machine (14.02 LTS) and I am trying to run a Yacc program for the first time (Lex programs work fine), but i am getting the following error:

***parser name defined to default :"parse"***

The code I have entered in is as follows:

### 1b.lex

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
extern yylval;
%}
%%
[0-9]+ {yylval=atoi(yytext);return num;}
[\+\-\*\/] {return yytext[0];}
[)] {return yytext[0];}
[(] {return yytext[0];}
. {;}
\n {return 0;}
%%
```

### 1b.y

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
%}
%token num
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
input:exp {printf("%d\n",$$);exit(0);}exp:exp'+'exp {$$=$1+$3;}
|exp'-'exp{$$=$1-$3;}
|exp'*'exp{$$=$1*$3;}
|exp'/'exp { if($3==0){printf("Divide by Zero\n");exit(0);}
else
$$=$1/$3;}
|'('exp')'{$$=$2;}
|num{$$=$1;};
%%
int yyerror()
{
printf("error");
exit(0);
}
int main()
{
printf("enter an expression\n");
yyparse();
}
```

Commands keyed in to get output
lex 1b.lex   (Successful)
yacc –d 1b.y (I get the error when i key in this line)

The code I have must according to my knowledge be 100% correct, as I copiedit out from my college manual just to check whether or not my lex and yacc works fine.

Maybe I missed something during the installation procedure?

---

Command keyed in to install lex and yacc

> 1. sudo apt-get update
>    2.sudo apt-get install flex
>    3.sudo apt-get install bison
>    4.sudo apt-get install byacc
>    5.sudo apt-get install bison++
>    6.sudo apt-get install byacc -j

All the commands mentioned above were successfully ran.

Comment: Is there a reason to install all those yacc derivatives when you just use plain `yacc`? Does the error not occur when you don't? I'm asking because I've called `yacc` on your script and it finished without any errors.

Comment: How do i just call yacc on my script? Could you state the steps you took? I am a beginner.

Comment: I did it the same way you wrote you did it. `yacc –d 1b.y` According to the question this is the line that gave the error, isn't it?

Comment: And you didn't install any packages? Like sudo apt-get install bison?

Comment: From the ones you'd listed I have `bison`. `yacc` on my system is aliased to it. That may be a clue. `yacc` on your system may be an alias to some other program that doesn't support some syntax you've used. Try to explicitly use `bison`, `byacc` and `bison++` and see which of them works.

Comment: It works. Sweet. I just required  sudo apt-get install bison